# Install Composer with portable xampp

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to install `composer` with `xampp` portable. When I download and run the setup file, it gives me following error.

[image]

I have set `php` path in my environmental variables

Comment: Did you run PHP from the command line, as suggested?

Comment: Nops. I am installing it from the exe

Comment: Well, then try it and see if you get a clearer error message. The PHP error log could contain information as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'had the same issue and solved it putting full path for `extension_dir` and `browscap` in php.ini:

```
e:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini
```

instead of:

```
\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini
```